# How to find items that are in one dstore collection but not in another?

Tags: dojo, dstore

Suppose I have two dstore collections: value1 and value2.

I want to find out what items are in value1 but not in value2. So something like this:

```
var filterCollection = value1.filter(function(item) {
    return value2.notExists(item);
})；
```

But "notExists" function, well, doesn't exist. How do I make this logic work?

Comment: As per the [docs](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Collection.md) it does not allow a function to be passed to the filter. Also the **Filter** contstructor object contains the **in** operator but not what you require **not in** or **not exists** operator. If dstore is not a constratint than the `dojo/Memory` store can be used which allow you to pass a function as an argument to the filter which can be used to meet your requirements.

Comment: Please consider creating a JSFIDDLE with your dstore and some example of your data thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this feature is not included by default in `dstore`, you can write your own function for comparing the content of your `dstores` and use the result as you wish.

Here a generic example. You need to populate `value1` and `value1` with the content of your `dstore`.

Simplified example.

http://jsbin.com/fozeqamide/edit?html,console,output

Version without using indexOf()

http://jsbin.com/nihelejodo/edit?html,console,output

The way how you loop in your `datastore` is related to its data structure.

Notes: This is a generic example as the question does not provide any source code, nor an example of data in `dstore`.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Builder</title>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        window.app = {
            value1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 8], // populate with date for valu1 dstore
            value2: [1, 2, 6, 4, 8], // populate with date for valu1 dstore
            valueNotExists: [],
            start: function () {
                this.notExists();
            },
            notExists: function () {
                this.valueNotExists = this.value1.filter(function (x) {
                    return this.value2.indexOf(x) < 0;
                }.bind(this));
                console.log(this.valueNotExists);
            },
        };
    </script>

</head>

<body onload="window.app.start();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't work. value2 is NOT an array, it's a dstore Collection. It don't have 'indexOf' method.

Comment: This answer works if the collections are converted to arrays first.

Comment: @AllenZhang thanks for your comment. My answer is a "generic example", I just trying to propose a general solution to your problem. I made an edit to my question. Regarding indexOf you can use instead a simple loop, it must be tweaked accordingly to your data structure. Please let me know if I can support you more on this question. Thanks.

Comment: your answer is great. It does solve the problem. It just too generic so that it won't work for dstore (which is what the question was about). I'm happy to accept this as long as readers know how to apply this answer to dstore.